# PHP script echoes its own content when run via Ajax on Lion

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, osx-lion

I'm having what to me is a weird problem, and I'm wondering if you can help me figure out the shamefully obvious mistake I'm making.

I have a javascript app that runs a bunch of php scripts via ajax, all running locally on my Mac, using the built-in apache server. It's been working for years, but on my new Lion Mac, the php scripts no longer return the files they're supposed to be reading. They return the php script itself.

The php scripts work fine if I run them from the command line. They work fine if I run them directly from the command line. They work fine run from Ajax on a Snow Leopard computer. They do not work if Ajax runs them on my Lion Mac.

Things I have tried :

- I have adjusted httpd.conf so that the php module loads, and I have  restarted my Mac.
- Apache is definitely running: 127.0.0.1/~myname/ gets the "it works"  msg.
- I have tried running the ajax using jquery and using the  old-fashioned longhand ways. Same problem. (I have made sure that      jquery is in fact loading.)
- I am not using the short code "<?" in my php scripts
- The php file is in the same directory as the html and javascript  files. The permissions are the same as the permissions on the Snow Leopard computer where it all works fine

I've tried googling for this up and down, but I'm stumped. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: If you go to the ajax url (i.e. http://localhost/~myname/ajax-page.php), does the page load fine then, or do you get the source still. Basically, if not loaded via ajax, does it work?

Comment: Yup, it works. It only doesn't work when loaded via Ajax on this one Mac, which happens to be the one running Lion, although that may not be the relevant difference, of course.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to have been that php 5.3.1 was installed on my Lion machine. When I updated to php5.4, it began working again.

To update to php5.4, I followed the instructions here: http://php-osx.liip.ch/ Thanks for your help, Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

- Is php enabled and configured properly?
  Edit your `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` and make sure the line: `LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so` exists, then re-start Apache: `sudo apachectl restart`
- Is the correct/expected `php.ini` being loaded?
  *[On Lion-upgrade the `php.ini` file will be renamed to `/etc/php.ini-5.2-previous` and a new sample PHP configuration file, `/etc/php.ini.default` is put in place](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4786)!!!*
  Hence you probably might want to reconfig your php.ini file.
- Extensions previously installed under `/usr/lib/php/extensions/.../` had been removed.
  So, if you have extensions that you wish to still use with 5.3, they will need to be re-built.
- Can you now load a phpinfo.php file containing `<?php phpinfo();?>`.
- Now check the phpinfo for the mySQL directives (and other locals) if you use it.
- Apple has included the Suhosin patch and extension.
  Suhosin is part of the [Hardened-PHP project](http://www.hardened-php.net) which aims to protect PHP applications against buffer-overflow and format string vulnerabilities. Compare Suhosin's [feature-list](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/a_feature_list.html) to your php-scripts.
- Might there be deprecated php statements being used (that worked in a older version of php)?

Does it work now?

Comment: Thanks, GitaarLAB, but I'm still coming up empty.

Comment: Ack. Didn't know ReturnKey would submit the comment. I had taken care of the LoadModule line and the restart already. But I didn't know about the php.ini change. Very promising! So I copied php.ini from my Snow Leopard machine (where it works), and restarted apache. Same problem. I could and still can load the phpinfo file via the browser. The php version on the SL machine is 5.3.8, and is 5.3.1 on the Lion machine, but the php script is doing something very simple: reading a file line by line. (There are a bunch of more complex php scripts that are also broken.)

Comment: Try to reconfigure the new php.ini file instead of copying/reusing the 'old' one. Also see updated answer about Suhosin patch and removed extensions. You COULD also try to install plain vanilla php 5.3.8 (like your SL machine) on your Lion machine, see how that goes.

Comment: I was afraid you were going to suggest that :) Since I don't actually know how to configure php.ini, when I get back to work and have my machine in front of me, I'll try to figure it out. Thanks for the suggestion. I'll report back on Monday.

Comment: The new php.ini makes no difference. I am unable to figure out how to upgrade to 5.3.1, after having spent a lot of time this morning with macports.

Comment: Did you check suhosin's featurelist? Just to be sure you didn't miss that in my updated checklist. If it was me, I'd try a plain vanilla php (5.3.8) just to find out if that would work, and getting a better idea if it was mac-os or apple's php version that caused the blues. Otherwise I'm out of idea's, I only know mac's from images.. and I'm told they don't have a right-click button. No seriously, I have no idea anymore, I just used google and compiled a list of all documented (cross-verifiable) problems I could find that caused the same problem you are experiencing. Good luck and post back!

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep working on it. Maybe I can even figure out how to upgrade to 5.3.8.

Comment: Installing php5.4 fixed the problem! I installed it by following the instructions here: http://php-osx.liip.ch/ Thanks, GitaarLAB. (I'm now going to answer my own question, which I hope does not violate Stackoverflow rules!)